# How to build the project with different configuration setting on TeamCity

Tags: .net, msbuild, teamcity

I have been compiling a project solution which have different configuration settings for building the project. something like this.

[image]

Now I have some specific settings on the project which uses `"Debug with Envers"` and now I want to build the project on the command line with MsBuild. But when I do so it uses the default `Debug` settings and my project that need `envers` is also built through `debug` configuration.

Can I specify something that will build the project based on the envers ?

The command line would be something like this :

```
MSBuild YourSolution.sln /p:Configuration=Debug(or Your preferred conf)
```

Comment: It's not clear, have tried `/p:Configuration="Debug with Envers"` or not? May be you forgot the quotes?

Comment: yes I was writing it without quotes. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why build from the command line when TeamCity has a Visual Studio solution type that is designed for this and you can easily specify the configuration type to build

[image]